# How to use user entered variables in a GET request?

Tags: c#

I need to take a user entered string and send it as a search query in a GET request for a search engine API named WordTracker. I hard coded the search query into the request and that works. I unfortunately do not know much of APIs, I'm learning as I go. How would one go about this task?

My code, using the api documentation:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://api3.wordtracker.com");

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");

     using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri: "search/stats?keywords[]=token&app_id=d******4&app_key=d*****d)
     {
           string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You should edit your question to clarify and include a [mcve].

Comment: I think [string interpolation](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation) is what you are looking for, but as maccettura said, your question is too vague to answer properly.

Comment: are you trying to send the GET request or are you trying to process the GET, ie are you a client or a server

Comment: I've tried to explain myself better. I hope this helps explain myself better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want so it's not hard-coded to token:

```
var keyWord = "KEYWORDTOSEARCH"; # you'd replace this

var baseAddress = new Uri("http://api3.wordtracker.com");
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri: "search/stats?keywords[]=" + keyWord  + "&app_id=d******4&app_key=d*****d)
{
string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes! I just tried that and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: can you please "accept"?  on screen option.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

although there is an accetped answer I think a better solution is

```
var url = String.Format("search/stats?keywords[]={0}&app_id={1}&app_key={2}",
     keyword,id,key);
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri: url)
```

once you get beyond one variable building strings via + is messy.

Latest c# version also has

```
var url = $"search/stats?keywords[]={keyword}&app_id={id}&app_key={key}";
```